# How to download a picture from the uri directly to xaml in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uri

How I can  download a picture from the uri directly to xaml in Xamarin.
I using gravatar in classic ASP  [link to gravatar](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/12/29/using-gravatar-in-classic-asp/)

example

```
 <flv:FlowListView SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding FollowersItem}" FlowColumnMinWidth="110" FlowItemsSource="{Binding FollowerItems}">
                            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Padding="3">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                       <Image>
                                            <Image.Source>
                                                <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding EmailHash, StringFormat='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id={0}'}" />
                                            </Image.Source>
                                        </Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        </flv:FlowListView>
```

EmailHash initializes correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the image source to an uri, it implicitly converts it.

```
 <Image Source="{Binding EmailHash, StringFormat='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id={0}'}" />
```

Comment: did not work. Even if I put the directly path
<Image Source="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=a116db2890f78b5934eaa2f5d5e7ce56" />

Comment: try setting a background color to the image and check if its visible at all. I tried this url: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar which showed me the blue avatar image with a white on/off switch in it

Comment: Btw, you have to have elements in the listviews ItemsSource property to show the grid you have defined

Comment: yes, I also got this blue picture in this code <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding EmailHash, StringFormat='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id={0}'}" />

 But I did not get an avatar

Now I see that this is a problem on gravatar